# Nested Repeater with group using ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I am having trouble with displaying ACF fields, Im using the pro version of ACF, here is a diagram of what I did in ACF

```
series (repeater)
- event_group (group)
-- series_year (text)
-- series_year_details (repeater)
--- series_event (text)
--- series_date (date)
--- series_view (file)
```

I want it to show like this

```
**2018**
event name 1 - July 24, 2018 >
event name 2 - July 28, 2018 >
event name 3 - July 30, 2018 >

**2017**
event name 4 - June 24, 2018 >
event name 5 - June 28, 2018 >
event name 6 - June 30, 2018 >
```

the arrow ( > ) is a link to the file.

Here is My current code

```
<?php
if( have_rows('series') ): 
    while( have_rows('series') ): the_row(); ?>
        <div>
            <h3><?php the_sub_field('series_year'); ?></h3>
            <?php if( have_rows('series_year_details') ): ?>
                <ul>
                <?php while( have_rows('series_year_details') ): the_row(); ?>
                    <li>
                    <?php echo the_sub_field('event'); ?><br>
                    <?php the_sub_field('date'); ?><br>
                    <?php the_sub_field('view'); ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>  

    <?php endwhile;
    endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know

```
<?php
    if( have_rows('series') ): 
      while( have_rows('series') ): the_row(); ?>
        <div>
            <h3><?php the_sub_field('series_year'); ?></h3>
            <?php if( have_rows('series_year_details') ): ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php while( have_rows('series_year_details') ): the_row(); ?>
                    <li>
                    event name : <?php echo the_sub_field('event'); ?> -  <?php the_sub_field('date'); ?> <a href="<?php the_sub_field('view'); ?>"> > </a><br>
                    </li>
                   <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>  

    <?php endwhile;
    endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, tried it and it does not work, there is nothing displaying

Comment: Can you please attach  all array with print_r() format